# Android test code for an application?

Tags: java, android

I will have to say that I am new to the Android development world. I just download it yesterday and would like to see if I can get a couple of simple application working tonight.

The code before is what I have when I put a button the screen. I have a good understanding about XML and Java so I am not new at this concept, but I will have to say that I tried to get an Android application to work a while back and it was ran into problem after problem and never did see an example run. This cannot be that complex of a problem.

I know that there are some test device that are in the Eclipse IDE that I an emulate a Nexus 7. I have a Nexus 7 and would like to see about testing it even on my own device but first I have to get it to even run in some emulation. This is what I cannot seem to figure out.

My question is where am I going wrong?

To be exact how do you get an Android application to compile and run so you can see what it is on the screen of either an emulator or a Nexus 7. I do not actually see any Java code but rather XML base code. Is that how the Android system runs on XML based code?

Android Code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="301dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: And What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Exactly what ^-- that guy said. Plus, show your java code that you use along side this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't just depend on XML code, the above XML code is from the file someActivity.xml
XML is used to define the interface of an activity. If you are using eclipse , then refer the image in this url http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Image:Eclipse_android_4.2_main_screen.png

The /src/ folder contains all the Java files, Each Activity in an Android Application is defined with an XML file and a Java file. You can also create Java files, just as an additional functionality supporting a Java activity file.

The /gen/ folder contains all the auto-generated files. Refer developer.android.com for further details on this.

The /bin/ folder contains the binaries that are generated or compiled. .apk file which you have to deploy in your android device will be generated or created every time you Build the project.

The /libs/ folder contains external Libraries that you wish to add to support your application.

The /res/ folder contains all the resources that are needed to run your application. The term resources doesn't mean RAM, Storage disk, it means the image files that you use in the application, e.g: Logo, Background Image e.t.c., Images should be placed in /res/drawable-xxx/ folder, xxx, it means you should place your image in different DPI or resolution formats, refer image editing using photoshop for further details about resizing your image to a specified size. 
        The /values/ folder contains XML files which define the Strings,Colors etc., that you'd be using in your application.
The /res/Layout/ folder contains all the layouts for each activity. These are defined in XML format to describe the interface of the activity in a robust manner.

Finally, The AndroidManifest.xml file contains all the details regarding the activity that you'd like to launch on start of the application, The permissions that are needed to be given to the application in accordance with the security of the Android device and its user details.

You will code your Business logic in java files and the presentation logic in XML files.

refer this url for creating a hello world Application, in Android.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Example_Android_Application

Comment: Were is the XML file stored again. I had it on the screen and then closed it thinking that I would find it and then could not. I went through all of the directors a couple of times and I did not see it there.

Comment: this is the file I am not finding  AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: xxxLayout.xml files are stored in /res/layout/ folder, and AndroidManifest.xml is stored in / directory, [ / --> /root root dir of the project ]